# customer can not login on chrome browser in magento 2.1.8

Tags: magento-2.1, login, customer-account, chrome-browser

When a customer puts his e-mail and password and clicks Submit, the page refreshes and leaves the fields empty, without logging in.While other browser allowing login of customers to their account.  Please help me to find out the solution.Thanks

Comment: Clear browser cache. Remove var/* , pub/static (without htaccess).

Comment: i have done all these things.. but same result

Comment: I assumed you were using Chrome browser and use `localhost`, ex: `http://localhost/mage218` as top level domain. Try to use another domain, for example: `mage218.loc`, `mysite.loc`...

Comment: any other solution...??